# What is the difference between [Dictionary<String, Any>] and [String: Any]

Tags: swift, dictionary

In swift I have seen `[Dictionary<String, Any>]` and `[String: Any]`. Both seems to do the same thing. Is there any difference? Is one better or preferable over the other?

Comment: Did I ask a question too broad? or unrelated? What's going on?

Comment: @matt I didn't see that. Please mark this as duplicate and vote down.

Answer (score 3):

One is actually an array containing elements of the other.

`[String:Any]` is shorthand for `Dictionary<String:Any>`, while `[Dictionary<String:Any>]` is shorthand for `Array<Dictionary<String:Any>>`, which can be written as `[[String:Any]]`.

If you want to use the shorthand notation for arrays/dictionaries, keep in mind that an Array can be written as `[Element]`, while a Dictionary as `[Key:Value]`. `Element`, `Key` and `Value` here represent concrete types such as `String`, `Int`, `Any`, etc. Notice the `:` in the Dictionary notation and the fact that you need two types, one for the key and one for the value when declaring a dictionary.

Comment: You should make it clear that `Element`, `Key`, and `Value` need to represent types such as `String`, `Any`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

They're the same. The `[X:Y]` syntax is called a dictionary literal; the `Dictionary<X, Y>` syntax is the explicit form. (If you meant `[Dictionary<X, Y>]` that'd be an array of dictionaries, which is different.)

As for whether one is better than another, it's mostly a style choice. I primarily see people using the literal syntax over the explicit syntax in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you really mean `Dictionary<String, Any>` and `[String: Any]`.

They are merely notations for the same thing:

- Dictionary is a generic parameterized on the key type and the value type, so `Dictionary<String,Any>` uses generic type notation.
- The shorthand `[String:Any]` is just that — a shorthand ("syntactic sugar"), built into the language as being more pleasant / intuitive.

But `[Dictionary<String,Any>]` is something else yet again; it is the same as `[[String:Any]]` or `Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>`. And again, those are equivalent because Array is a generic, but the `[Type]` syntax is built in as syntactic sugar.